# Icon missing on uninstall wp-cache plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

When I uninstalled the Wp-cache plugin from my Wordpress theme, the star rating icon started showing the letter 'S' instead of the star icon.

Any suggestion as to how to get the star icon back?

Woo-commerce CSS:

```
.woocommerce .star-rating:before {
  content: "\e021\e021\e021";
  color: #d3ced2;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "star";
}
```

Please help me to get my icon back.

Comment: I think that your font file went missing. Check it.

Comment: Also, please use http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of questions.

Comment: May be try have a look in the `wp-confing.php` file for `define('WP_CACHE', TRUE);` to be changed as `define('WP_CACHE', FALSE);`. And in your `wp-content` folder delete if remaining a `advanced-cache.php` file and a `cache` folder. Come back to your browser, empty cache and reload…

Comment: HI eric there is no ('WP_CACHE', TRUE); in my config.php and i also delete all cache file from folder.....don't know what to do http://www.craftsforyou.in/ this is my website

Comment: there is no define('WP_CACHE', TRUE); in my wp-confing.php and also i removed all cache files from backed but problem still alive....Pls help me What i do [http://www.craftsforyou.in/]